# Composite key with user-supplied string column, foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, relational-database, composite-primary-key, data-integrity, relational-model

Let's say I have the following table

```
TABLE subgroups (
    group_id        t_group_id NOT NULL REFERENCES groups(group_id),
    subgroup_name   t_subgroup_name NOT NULL,
    more attributes ...
)
```

- `subgroup_name` is UNIQUE to a `group(group_id)`.
- A `group` can have many `subgroups`.
- The `subgroup_names` are user-supplied. (I would like to avoid using a `subgroup_id` column. `subgroup_name` has meaning in the model and is more than just a label, I am providing a list of predetermined names but allow a user to add his owns for flexibility).
- This table has 2 levels of referencing child tables containing subgroup attributes (with many-to-one relations);

I would like to have a PRIMARY KEY on (group_id, upper(trim(subgroup_name)));

From what I know, postgres doesn't allow to use PRIMARY KEY/UNIQUE on a function.
IIRC, the relational model also requires columns to be used as stored.

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON subgroups (group_id, upper(trim(subgroup_name)));` doesn't solve my problem
as other tables in my model will have FOREIGN KEYs pointing to those two columns.

I see two options.

Option A)

- Store a cleaned up subgroup name in subgroup_name
- Add an extra column called subgroup_name_raw that would contained the uncleaned string

Option B)

- Create both a UNIQUE INDEX and PRIMARY KEY on my key pair. (seems like a huge waste)

Any insights?

*Note: I'm using Postgres 9.2*

Comment: Why would you want to store an un-cleaned-up version of subgroup_name? I'm trying to figure out your thinking. Surely you have clean versions of group+subgroup ids and a lookup table to give a display name.

Comment: I would want the un-cleaned-up version to display in the user interface. I would not want to display an uppercased-version and I want to make sure the name is case-insensitively unique.

A subgroup will have members, messages and other objects attached to it. Tables containing these objects will have a foreign key to the subgroups table. I see a clean subgroup_name as an equivalent to a subgroup_id.

Comment: So if it's for user display, you'll want to put it in a lookup table anyway. They'll presumably want to change the display-name at some point. They always do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do a UNIQUE constraint on the output of a function.  You can't do it in the table definition though.  What you need to do is create a unique index after.  So something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX subgroups_ukey2 ON subgroups(group_id, upper(trim(subgroup_name)));
```

PostgreSQL has a number of absolutely amazing indexing capabilities, and the ability to create unique (and partial unique) indexes on function output is quite underrated.